# if condition not recognised in foreach in Razor view

Tags: c#, html, sql

Please may somebody help me with my query. I am using Web Matrix with CSHTML, a database sat behind using SQL querying and C#.

```
var query = "SELECT Seat_Row, Seat_No, Booked FROM Seating_Plan WHERE Seat_Row = 'A'"; 
var db = Database.Open("TheatreBooking");
```

Here I have my SQL query and my database. 
Then in the html `<body>` I have the following:

```
@foreach (var item in db.Query(query)) 
{ 
    if ( @item.Booked = 1 ) 
    { 
        <img src="images/unavaliable.jpg" alt="Avaliable Seat" width="30" height="30"> 
    } 
}
```

The problem I am having is that within my "if" statement, the `@item.Booked` isn't found, however, if I taken this outside the "if" statement, the @ highlights as meant to be and I can return the variable say for example nested in the `<p>` tags.

The error I am currently getting is "'WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord' does not contain a definition for 'Booked' "

Thanks

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good title?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

Comment: not actuall solution for your problem, but might save you a facepalm later -  `@item.Booked == 1` you want to check if it is equal, not assign i think

Comment: You could try making a [strongly typed db query](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2011/01/24/strongly-typed-data-access-with-webmatrix-data/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the @ symbol should work:

```
if ( item.Booked = 1 )
```

Comment: I'm, guessing it should be double equals too.

Comment: and comparison operator instead of assignment one... :)

Comment: And also thanks to everyone who pointed out the == *facepalm*